# do any of these nosql db's have GUI explorers?

Tags: nosql

do any of these nosql type databases have GUI explorers where you can run queries, view the "tables" and their attributes etc?

Comment: Try Pentaho (http://www.pentahobigdata.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see how this is a major goal of any scalable database. You could certainly use time to make some swanky visual tool, but

- These data sets are usually so big that ad-hoc queries run against a production system will return too much data to be useful
- Developers have enough real problems to think about - like working out a compromise between availability, consistency and partition-tolerance

Comment: Strange then that data warehousing tools (which deal with truly gigantic datasets - every item sold by Walnart, for example)  have provided such facilities for years. And is "scalable database" the new euphemism for "databases for dimwits"?

Answer (score 1):

couchDB does: visit the `http://localhost:5984/_utils/` once installed.

Comment: On Mac, there's also CouchDBX (http://janl.github.com/couchdbx/) which basically wraps the web-based front-end in a stand-alone app. It's an nicely polished database front-end, especially considering it's in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When using a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) visualization of the data comes in very handy during both development and debugging. For the [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) open source graph database there is [Neoclipse](http://neoclipse.org/), which can be used both to model the domain during development and to peek into an existing database; and [neoviz](http://github.com/obruening/neoviz), a Rails based visualization tool for Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are some in the works for MongoDB:

http://github.com/sbellity/futon4mongo

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

http://www.mongohq.com